# No Internet access on guest Ubuntu

Tags: vmware-player

I know there are many related questions, but I wasn't able to solve my problem.

### Problem: No internet on guest Ubuntu

### Specs:

1. **Host OS:** Windows XP
2. **Guest OS:** Ubuntu 11.10
3. **VM software:** VMWare Player
4. Internet access on host via organization LAN, with company firewalls installed.
5. VMWare Tools installed

### Approaches tried:

1. Tried sharing my LAN connection with other users. (Properties -> Advanced -> "Allow other users...")
2. Tried changing the option from LAN to bridge connections. (VM Settings)

Though, I'm not sure if I attempted the above approaches correctly, especially considering that I don't know much about how these settings work and also considering the company firewall that exists.

#### If you think this question has be asked already, it would help if you could point to the right link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to set the **Network proxy**.

Here's how I did it:

1. Go to **System Settings**
2. Choose **Network** under **Hardware**
3. Select **Network proxy** on the left pane
4. Select **Manual** under the Method dropdown
5. Set the **HTTP Proxy** and **port number** based on what your organization uses

I'm not exactly sure what's happening here. I had to ask someone in my company for the details to fill in step 5.